# How to embed SCC closed caption file into a video file mov/mp4/mpg

Tags: ffmpeg, pyffmpeg

I am trying to embed a closed caption (SCC) file into a video file and hitting on some problems.

Please suggest how to embed SCC closed caption file into a video file mov/mp4/mpg

Does FFMPEG support closed captions - scc files as input ?

Which open source tools can I use to do the above task ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: @Tennyx I donʼt know about OP but ffmpeg does now support SCC as input and output, but does not yet support putting closed caption into mp4 streams; you have to convert it to another format.  Theyʼre working on it at very low priority.  Also SCC reading and writing is slightly buggy but that should only matter if you care about frame-perfect captions, or need to process other tools that get confused by the slightly wrong timestamps, or if you use 8080 padding mid-line and meet a couple other conditions.